# Printer MAC Addresses

Tags: printing

I have three printers that I have to put on our internal network using the printers' internal NICs.  They are all currently attached to Windows XP machines and shared via the OS.

So I need to submit details to the networking folks to get IP addresses for each printer.

How do I find the MAC addresses of these printers (they are all HP LaserJets)?

**Edit:**

Printers:

- HP LaserJet 3050
- HP LaserJet 1600
- HP LaserJet 2420

All are attached via USB currently.

**Edit:**

None of the printers currently have IP addresses.  They all have the capability but currently are not setup.

Comment: Does the 1600 have a built-in card or an external box?

Comment: the 1600 has a built-in card

Comment: The HP Color LaserJet 1600 does not have an ethernet jack built-in.  Please check the model again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you did a 'test page', did you do it from the client machine or the printer?... if you did it from the client machine, I doubt you'll get good information about network settings of the printer (specially if you're connecting through USB).

Doing a quick google you can find the manual for your 3050, check for others:

**Network configuration page**
The Network configuration page lists the current settings and properties of the all-in-one. To print the Network configuration page from the all-in-one, complete the following steps:

1. On the control panel, press Menu.
2. Use the < or the > button to select
   Reports, and then press .
3. Use the
   < or the > button to select Network
   report, and then press .

Answer (score 2):

Print a test page with the network configuration from the printers.  If they have a NIC in them the test page should display the mac.  I believe LaserJets also have the mac printed on one of the physical labels on the case.  You might have to open a drawer or lift a lid somewhere to find it, depending on what model LJ.

Comment: i tried the test page with no luck.  i will scourer the case for the addresses physically on them. thanks for the ideas.

Comment: Are you sure there's a NIC in them then?  The configuration page should say something about a JetDirect if the printer is seeing them.  You should also get a page kicked out with the JetDirect configuration if the printer recognizes the card.

Comment: yes...all there have ethernet jacks

Comment: Squillman, he doesn't know what he is talking about.

Comment: The other thing you can do is download the JetDirect software, plug the printers into the network and have the software find them.  You don't need IP to do that.  Other then that *shrug*

Comment: @squillman thanks for the feedback and thanks for not being a jerk about it.

Answer (score 1):

**HP LaserJet 3050**

page 271

http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00495173/c00495173.pdf

---

**HP LaserJet 2420**

page 85

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00224567/c00224567.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I would try a broadcast ping to `255.255.255.255` from a linux box (Windows does not allow this) given they are on the same switch. Then have a look at the arp-cache for any responses using

```
arp -a
```

The arp cache lookup will also work if you can somehow connect to the device using a configuration tool (even if does not show you the MAC address).

Answer (score 0):

There should be a menu choice to print configuration (on the printer itself). Other than that (or using an application that might have come with the printer for configuration, that might report a MAC address), I do not know.

Comment: he doesn't have the IP address so how will he ping

Comment: TStamper is correct no ip addresses

Comment: Berek, you should reword your entry. You wrote "I have three printers that I have to but on our internal network using the printers' internal NICs." But later you say they are attached via USB. I assumed, by your first sentence, that there were IPs assigned.